# How to store Avatar Images in JBoss' specific folder

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

After the user has signed in, I want to show default profile images: two different depending on the user's gender.

Before that i want to store these two avatar images in `jboss/standalone/images` directory by using java code or image servlet code.

Comment: If there are always those two avatar as choices, why not store the images during deployment and simply show the right one after the user has selected their gender?

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

1) In the db, where you store informations about the user (user table) you can have a column which stores the path (url) to the image, with a default value to man avatar or woman avatar, depending on the gender. This path can be passed to the src in `<img>` tag.

2) If the user decide to change his avatar (from a list of avatars disponible on the server), you must update in it's column to the corresponding path, which is selected new avatar.

Comment: Thanks for your response,

Comment: Thanks for your response, All the Url in user(user table) is fine.But my doubt is,In userprofile imageurl path is    ../..../image/mandoctor.png.  In Standalone i have one images folder it is created at war file deployment time.In that images there is no avatars present i want to store the man avatar and women avatar at that images folder  can you please give me help to store that avatars in standalone/images folder.

Comment: @MadanMohan You say what you create a image folder on the server when the app (war) is deployed? Why?

Comment: Our leader requirement is creating an images folder at the time of deployment time.I asked that question to my leader they said to me like ,create an images folder at the time of app deployment and create users folders with user id(profileid) at the time of signup time.User want to singnin we can show him a default avatars ...Let me know if you understand my question otherwise i can try to give my question clearly to you.

Comment: @MadanMohan and if you redeploy your app, what happens with all the folders in your root image folder? Does the process overwrite it and all the data is lost?

Comment: Once i can deploy my app again we redeploy our app is any changes(new features) we have done in our app then only we redeploy our app yes..i think we need to take back up of that images every time..

Comment: no need to take backup also .The images data is permanently stored in with      respective  userids directory folder.whenever we redeploy an war file the data is stored in server. that it..

Comment: if already folder  present with userid then it dont allow to create a folder with same id.If doesn't it will allow.all the images data are stored in server .After redeploy old customer is trying to login  then the profile picture is came  whatever image present in userprofile id directory that image will be displayed.